# Does setting and int to 0 save on memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, refactoring

I'm going through an old code base and fixing issues that pop up with xCode's static analyzer. The issue that shows is that the value is never read and basically what is happening in this method is that it's taking a string that should be a number and casting it to an int. Here is the line in question though:

```
if (len50 == CANNOT_CALCULATE)
{
     len50 = 0;
     strLen50 = @"";
}
```

Cannot_Calculate is a macro for a certain int that means it wasn't casted correctly and there's an else statement that does stuff with the int it it was casted correctly. The objects len50 and strLen50 aren't used at all after this if check, hence the reason of the warning from the analyzer.

My question is if this line is necessary? Does setting a int to 0 or string to an empty string save on memory? If it does then the owner of the codebase will want it in, but it doesn't then I might as well get rid or it.

Comment: what is `strLen50` bool? Also if it can't calculate then original coder wants to have default values like `0`

Comment: `strLen50` is the string that was trying to be casted. And I would assume so too about the default values but the variables are used again before going out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That be some weird code all the way around.

1) No, setting a variable to a value does not impact memory one way or another.  If the value is never read, it is a wasted line of code (that the compiler will likely optimize away anyway).

2) `!""` would be weird for setting a boolean value.

I'd be highly suspect of the rest of the codebase, having just read that.  (Having been a consultant on many projects, suspect code is oft a way of life.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. This is a really really old codebase and was developed in a hurry because of contracts. Also, I just noticed my typo, its `@""` not `!""` it's a string not bool.